# Use a service to send/receive data through a socket connection.

Tags: java, android, android-service

I have created a client-server application that the two parties communicate using a socket connection and input/output streams to send/receive data. It all works great but only if I have just one activity that uses the connection. Since I will be having more than just one activities in my application, and after some searching around, I've concluded that I have to create a Service which will handle the socket connection and sending/receiving from the socket streams. I've never worked with Services before and I thought I'd start one step at a time. At the moment I've just created a Service that creates an instance of my Client class(which extends Thread) and starts that thread, which establishes the connection to the server.
My Client class
**T_Client:**

```java
public class T_Client extends Thread {
    private static final String TAG = "T_Client";

    private static String serverIP = "192.168.2.3";
    private static int port = 4444;
    private InetAddress serverAddr = null;
    private Socket sock = null;
    private boolean running = false;
    private ObjectInputStream in;
    private ObjectOutputStream out;
    private Object objIn;

    public void send(MessageCustom _msg) {
        if (out != null) {
            try {
                out.writeObject(_msg);
                out.flush();

                Log.i("Send Method", "Outgoing : " + _msg.toString());
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Log.e("Send Method", ex.toString());
            }
        }
    }

    public void stopClient() {
        Log.v(TAG,"stopClient method run");
        running = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        running = true;
        try {
            serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIP);

            Log.i("TCP Client", "C: Connecting...");
            sock = new Socket(serverAddr, port);
            try {
                out = new ObjectOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());

                in = new ObjectInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
                Log.i(TAG, "C: Connected.");
                while (running) {
                    objIn = in.readObject();
                    Log.i("Object Read Class", objIn.getClass().toString());
                    Log.i("Object Read", objIn.toString());
                }
                Log.e("RESPONSE FROM SERVER", "S: Received Message: '" + objIn + "'");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "S: Error", e);
            } finally {
                out.close();
                in.close();
                sock.close();
                Log.i(TAG, "Closing socket: " + sock);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "C: Error", e);
        }
    }
}
```

My Service Class
**MyService:**

```java
public class MyService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "MyService";

    private T_Client client;

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.v(TAG, "onDestroy");
            if (client != null) {
                try {
                client.stopClient();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error on close: " + e);
                }
            }
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.v(TAG, "onStartCommand");

        client = new T_Client();
        client.start();

        Toast.makeText(this, "Service started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

All I do in my main activity at the moment is use a start and a stop button to start/stop the service

```java
public void start(View v){
    Log.i(TAG,"Start pressed");

    Intent intent=new Intent(getBaseContext(),MyService.class);
    startService(intent);
}

public void stop(View v){
    Log.i(TAG,"Stop pressed");

    Intent intent=new Intent(getBaseContext(),MyService.class);
    stopService(intent);
}
```

So my questions are:

1. What do I  have to do to send something using my Service?
2. How do I handle the objects that I read from the server so I can let the application know that something has been received, in real time?

Any input that could guide me towards resolving my issue is greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else comes across this question, that has a similar problem, I managed to solve my problem by playing around with code from these two posts

1. [Example: Communication between Activity and Service using
   Messaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300291/example-communication-between-activity-and-service-using-messaging?rq=1)
2. [How to keep the android client connected to the
   server even on activity changes and send data to server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14985678/how-to-keep-the-android-client-connected-to-the-server-even-on-activity-changes)