# Web socket connection for Android

Tags: java, android, ruby-on-rails

I am creating a websocket/server in ActionCable with Rails 5.

How do I go about connecting this with Android? I've seen a Socket.IO client with NodeJS, but nothing for Rails?

I would like the App to update in real time as well?

I  looked into Autobahn, but I really couldn't find Rails specific info?

Comment: Could you be a little more specific on your needs please ? What kind of exchanges do you want to settle between your Android device and your server ?

Comment: @Jackyto, JSON transfers. Say there is a teacher and a student. The teacher pushes a JSON question to the server, the server pushes it to the student real time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14985678/how-to-keep-the-android-client-connected-to-the-server-even-on-activity-changes). I think you  should use a [Service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) which is a background task running and waiting for instructions and a [Socket](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html) listening on a defined port on which your server will send your JSON.